# Shell script that uses "while" loop to read file gets stuck

Tags: bash, shell-script, python3

I have a python script which calls a shell script that is on a remote host to be executed which reads a file and does some manipulation as per the text pattern it encounters. I see that while it is trying to read a file through the while loop, even after reading the last line, the loop gets stuck. If I interrupt the python program with Ctrl+C, gives me the following stack trace.

### adr.py

```
ssh_command = [
            'ssh',
            '{}@{}'.format('user', i),
            'bash', '/tmp/checks.sh' 
        ] 
        ssh_command.append(i)
        # Execute the SSH command
        try:
            subprocess.run(ssh_command, check=True)
    
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            print('ERROR: Script execution failed with error code:', e.returncode)
```

### checks.sh

```
while read line; do
    if [[ $line =~ $pattern1 ]]; then
        echo -e "${line}\n${append_text}" | sudo tee -a "$file_path_tmp_new"
    elif [[ $line =~ $pattern2 ]]; then
        echo -e "${line}\n${append_text}" | sudo tee -a "$file_path_tmp_new"
    elif [[ $line =~ $pattern0 ]]; then
        echo -e "${line}\n${append_text}" | sudo tee -a "$file_path_tmp_new"
    else
        echo "$line" | sudo tee -a "$file_path_tmp_new"
    fi
done < "$file_path_tmp"
```

### Output:

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "adr.py", line 58, in <module>
    subprocess.run(ssh_command, check=True)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 495, in run
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1020, in communicate
    self.wait()
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1083, in wait
    return self._wait(timeout=timeout)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1806, in _wait
    (pid, sts) = self._try_wait(0)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1764, in _try_wait
    (pid, sts) = os.waitpid(self.pid, wait_flags)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Any help on what could be the problem here ? TIA

Comment: From the fact that `file_path_tmp` isn't set in the shell script, we can see that's not the script you're running. It should give an error when opening it. Either that, or you're passing the variables through the environment, but that's not shown either. Post the script that you are actually running and how you actually run it. In any case, is that Python script necessary for the problem to appear? What happens if you just run the script manually on the remote end?

Comment: A whole another question is if it makes any sense to do text manipulation like that with a shell, when you could use e.g. sed or Python for that.

Comment: Could the `sudo` commands on the remote end be waiting for a password?

Comment: try adding one or 2 `-t` options to the ssh command, to help sudo think it is being run by a user

Comment: check sh loop could be simplified? : `while read .... ; done < inputfile | sudo tee -a outputfile` . but the whole thing should be rewrote to not use a while read loop, I think (highly innefficient, and will do lots of side effects such as ignoring beginning and end of line spaces, use $IFS, etc)

Comment: lastly: try directing to a new file under /tmp, without using sudo, to see if sudo is the culpript

Comment: Actually, none of the necessary variables are set in that shell script. Please create a small example scenario that triggers the issue. One we can try ourselves. For example instead of that python code could you simply use `ssh -n user@remoteHost /tmp/checks.sh`?